# Congruence of Fourier coefficients of Siegel cusp forms

Tags: nt.number-theory, reference-request, algebraic-number-theory, modular-forms

Let $F$ be a Siegel cusp form of weight $2k$ and genus $2$ in the Maass subspace (i.e. the Saito-Kurokawa lift of some classical cusp form $f$ of weight $4k-2$); assume that $F$ and $f$ are Hecke eigenforms.

We know that there exists a $\omega_f\in\mathbb{C}$ such that

$$\frac{L_f(2k)}{\pi^{2k}\omega_f}$$

is algebraic, where $L_f$ is the L-function attached to $f$ (and $2k$ is the first critical value to the right of the center of simmetry of $L_f$). Let $\mathfrak{p}$ be a prime dividing said quantity in a suitable number field (containing $\mathbb{Q}_f=\mathbb{Q}\left((a_n(f))_n\right)$, the *finite* expansion of $\mathbb{Q}$ obtained by adjoining all the Fourier coefficients of $f$).

It is a result of Katsurada (https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s00209-007-0213-5) that there exists a Siegel eigenform $G$ (of weight $2k$ and genus $2$, orthogonal to $F$) whose Hecke eigenvalues are congruent to those of $F$ modulo $\mathfrak{p}$.

Let $F_A,G_A$ be the $A$-th Fourier coefficients of $F,G$ where $A$ is a $2\times 2$ matrix representing an integral positive semidefinite quadratic form. We assume $F$ and $G$ normalized so that each Fourier coefficient is algebraic, integral at $\mathfrak{p}$ and not all divisible by $\mathfrak{p}$.

> Can I find two indices $A,B$ such that matrix

$$\left(\begin{matrix} F_A & G_A\\ F_B & G_B\end{matrix}\right)$$

in invertible and has determinant not divisible by $\mathfrak{p}$?

While I can definitely find $A,B$ such that the matrix is invertible (otherwise $F$ and $G$ should be linearly dependent, but they are orthogonal) I have no idea about the determinant property. Actually it might even be false - for instance if $F$ and $G$ are congruent modulo $\mathfrak{p}$ coefficient-wise. Am I missing anything obvious? Any reference, help, or computational example would be great!

**EDIT:** according to Skoruppa, *Computations on Siegel modular forms of genus 2* (http://www.ams.org/journals/mcom/1992-58-197/S0025-5718-1992-1106982-0/S0025-5718-1992-1106982-0.pdf), Table 2, the non-SKLift Hecke eigenform he calls $\Upsilon 22$ is congruent modulo 1423 to an element of the cuspidal Maass subspace, which has dimension 3: let's consider $G=\Upsilon22$ and take an orthogonal basis of three SKLifts Hecke eigenforms (one of which is our $F$), where the condition about the congruence eigenvalues-wise follows from a different reason. Does this help? Should anything meaningful follow from this observation?